# How to use Core Audio in Swift language

Tags: swift, audio

I'm starting using Swift for my new audio app and I need to use Apple Core Audio library.

Let's be honest, Swift is a great language and I love it but as soon as we have to use C, pointers and other stuff it becomes really annoying to use it.

In order to make it a clear and clean interface I would to know you thoughts about interfacing Core Audio and Swift.

I thought to use C++ (for the convenients std::vector and more) or C but both require using bridging.

So my questions are:

1. Do you use pure Swift or C/C++Bridge when you use Core Audio?
2. Which one will be the faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the answers so I will leave it here if somebody is interested

1. The bridge approach is preferred. As [invalidname](https://stackoverflow.com/users/133621/invalidname) (Chris Adamson) said in [media framework talk](https://youtu.be/JNlHa9XTQz8) you have to *Render unto Caesar the things that are Caesar's, and unto God the things that are God's* i.e use C for C API and Swift for swifty things.
2. Talking about performance I found an [article](https://tetontech.wordpress.com/2014/07/07/swift-c-libraries-and-a-speed-test/%20%22article) which discusses about it. The conclusion is that for primitive type there is no problem by making all the type conversion, calling C function and making the backward type conversion. But for some type like String/char*, struct and more complicated type you could encoure performance decrease.

Btw don't hesitate to add more things if you think it could help other people.